# Any build-in function in MATLAB that can work like `ave` in R?

Tags: r, matlab, group-by

I am looking for a build-in function in `MATLAB` which can work in a similar way with `ave` in `R`.

---

Here is an example with `R`:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace = TRUE)
xid <- ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN = seq_along)
```

which gives

```
> x
 [1] "B" "A" "B" "A" "A" "B" "A" "A" "A" "B"
> xid
 [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 4
```

---

In other words, I have no idea which function in `MATLAB` allows me group by `x` and assign the sequence ids by groups, such that I can get an array like `xid`. I know `splitgroup` might be close to the goal, but it doesn't give me the desired output since it yields summarized results.

Comment: Could you explain the R code in a bit more detail? I'm trying to read the documentation for `ave` and `seq_along`, but find it hard to understand.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think it is: for each unique value indicate how many times it has occurred. I agree it should be better explained. `seq_along(v)` seems to be `1:numel(v)`

Comment: I love how the R docs have examples but don't show you the output of those examples.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Most docs pale comapre to Matlab's :-)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry that I missed adding explanation here. `ave(x,g, FUN = seq_along)` works like this: vector `x` is grouped by `g` (splitting `x` into groups by unique values in `g`) , and function `seq_along` is `1:numel(v)`, which assigns the indices to the elements within each group.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, your understanding is right.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just remembered why I quit R after trying to learn it for only half an hour. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question asks to replace each entry in `x` by the number of times it has occurred so far.

I don't know of a built-in function that does this. Here are some approaches. Let

```matlab
x = ['B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'B']; % example data. Row vector
```

- Short code, but memory-inefficient (computes an intermediate `N`×`N` matrix, where `N` is the length of `x`):

  ```matlab
  xid = sum(triu(x==x.'));
  ```
- A little more efficient (computes an intermediate `U`×`N` matrix, where `U` is the number of unique elements of `x` ):

  ```matlab
  t = x==unique(x).';
  xid = nonzeros(t.*cumsum(t,2)).';
  ```
- <s>Boring</s> efficient code with a loop:

  ```matlab
  xid = NaN(size(x)); % preallocate
  for u = unique(x)
      t = x==u;
      xid(t) = 1:sum(t);
  end
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works perfectly in a super smart way.